# How fast can i reach 1GB in firebase realtime database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase database and my question is, for example how fast can I reach 1GB if i have 100 users each storing worth 10 document pages of microsoft word full of text everyday, for one month?

Comment: it depend of the size of the word document.. after that it's basic multiplication math

Answer (score 0):

Word documents would be stored in Firebase Storage, not the realtime database. Realistically, the only way you will be billed anything for using the Firebase platform is if your app gets a significant of usage. I suspect that 99% of firebase apps do not generate any billing whatsoever. ...that's just a hunch.

If you do run into billing issues, that will/would be a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

Although this question is too broad since it lacks various variables like the number of users, size of the files and how this data is presented in the app I will try to give my $0.02 on this in a very generic way which can also be interpreted as how not to end up with a huge bill while using firebase,

Even though Firebase provides a sufficient space to test out the app in production there is a lot of ways in which things can go bad real quick like,
1) since firebase automatically handles the sync this additional read/write call comes out of your quota apart from the call you trigger [check-out](https://pamartinezandres.com/lessons-learnt-the-hard-way-using-firebase-realtime-database-c609b52b9afb) how one app developers found this out the hard way
2) if you have bad DB schema/design that you have not addressed, then you end up making multiple calls to the server to fetch the data which again bloats up the number of calls you make read about this [here](https://hackernoon.com/how-we-spent-30k-usd-in-firebase-in-less-than-72-hours-307490bd24d)
3) Not setting spending limits and alerts, this should be a mandatory step to avoid a lot of the above problems even though the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas) clearly gives an indication on how to set this up

These are some of the cases that I have come across I hope this serves as a guideline to set up your app